# Internal numpy looping order over two differently strided arrays

Tags: python, numpy, cpu-cache

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(100 * 100 * 100)
A.shape = (100, 100, 100)
B = A.copy()
B[:] = A.transpose(2, 0, 1)
```

Internally, is the looping order of the last copy well defined?  Does numpy prioritize `B`
's natural order or `A`'s?  Is the order different if I change the last line to `B[:] += A.transpose(2, 0, 1)`?

Context: I am interested effect of cache misses when copying arrays and am hoping to use simple numpy scripts to measure the cost.  However, to interpret numpy results I need to know what it is doing internally.

Comment: It looks like you mean `A.transpose(2, 0, 1)`.

Comment: `nditer` is the preferred way of iterating over arrays (though I don't know if every operation has been converted).  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html explains it, and includes a `cython` example.

Comment: What looping order? as far as i know, transpose only change the strides

Comment: Numpy is definitely at least a little smarter than that.  For instance, it definitely loops over 'C' ordered and 'F' ordered array axes in the opposite order.  I also think it does a series of operations like `B = A.copy(); B.T[:] = A.T` in the most efficient way.